# Canceling AsyncTask that is not running Calls onCancelled?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an Asynctask B that is executed from activity A.
On post execute of that B, on a certain condition B might create a new instance of itself and execute it.

What i did is put the AsyncTask declaration as global inside the B and overridden the onCancelled of B to cancel the new instance that is created onpostexecute.

so onDestroy of Activity A b.cancel() will also cancel the any AsyncTask executed onPostExecute.

```
  @Override
   protected void onCancelled()
   {
      if(currentPlansAsync != null)
      {
         currentPlansAsync.cancel(true);
      }
      super.onCancelled();
   }
```

And new instance of currentPlansAsync is called onPostExecute as follows:

```
 private void processAfterFailure()
   {

      if(this.counter < 3)
      {
         ProgressDialog progressDialog =
            GeneralUtils.showProgressDialog(parentActivity, parentActivity.getResources().getString(string.WaitDialogTitle),
               parentActivity.getResources().getString(string.WaitDialogMessage));
         this.counter++;
         currentPlansAsync = new CurrentPlansAsync(parentActivity, application, progressDialog, application.planBL, this.counter);
         currentPlansAsync.execute();

      }
      else
      {
         Toast.makeText(parentActivity, parentActivity.getResources().getString(string.SERVICE_ERROR), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

   }
```

**My question is that if AsyncTask B has stopped execution and it has executed another asynctask C and activity A goes to onDestroy and B is cancelled ( `b.cancel(true);`)
will onCancelled that is overridden in class B be called ??**

***This is so i ensure that i cancel the AsyncTask that was executed from the activity and also the AsyncTask executed from within that AsyncTask***

Comment: You can't cancel a task after it is completed. But you can make the `onCancelled` method public and call it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onCancelled()` is called immediately after the `doInBackground()` returns, if a `cancel()` call has been made before the background job has finished.
It will not be called if you `cancel()` the `AsyncTask` after that.

I would recommend to create a public method that will do what will cancel all child tasks, and call this public method:

```
public void cancelChildTasks()
{
    if(currentPlansAsync != null)
    {
        currentPlansAsync.cancel(true);
        currentPlansAsync.cancelChildTasks();
    }
}
```

You should still call and handle the `cancel()` method of the `AsyncTask`s in order to stop the `doInBackground()` execution if it is in the middle of execution. Just deal with the child tasks in the public methods instead of in the `onCancelled()`.