# AlertDialog not showing while cancelling AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I have got a little problem while cancellling a AsyncTask, which is in *a Fragment* which processes some data. If a internet session is expired the **AsyncTask should be cancelled and a dialog be shown** to inform the user.

However if I cancel the AsyncTask the AlertDialog is **not** shown, I also noticed that `onCancelled()`is **not** being called but the `onPostExecute()`is still executed.

If someone pls could assist?

**Edit:** If I use the while method, the AlertDialog is shown but how do I properly cancel the AsyncTask as the code as of `try`in `doInBackground()` still is being executed?

```
while (!isCancelled()) {
// Do stuff
}
```

**Edit 2:** Solved! It seemed the AsyncTask call was not correctly instinciated, below code works and now also **onCancelled method** is **called** and onPostExecute declined as it should be.
Cudos for *Anudeep Bulla* to point me in the right direction.

```
public class Tb3_Abonnement extends Fragment {

    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task;
...
@Override // If Fragment is visible to user, start asynctask
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if (isVisibleToUser) {
                // execute AsyncTask
                startFetch();
        }
    }
// Wrap (asynctask call) in a own method
public void startFetch() { 
        task = new FetchFacturen();
        task.execute();
    }

private class FetchFacturen extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
// Create new AlertDialog
        AlertDialog taskDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle("Mededeling Facturen:")
                .setMessage("Uw sessie is verlopen! U dient zich weer opnieuw in te loggen. ")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Start LoginActivity
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
                        getActivity().startActivity(mainIntent);
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .create();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (Helper.minutes <= 0) {
                task.cancel(true);
            } else {
                showProgress(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... result) {
            CharSequence cs1 = "€";
            if (isCancelled()) {
                util.disconnect();
                return null;
            }
                try {
                    // The heavy stuff
                        }

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() { //  Correctly called
            if(isCancelled()){
                Log.e("CANCELLED", "TAB3");
                this.taskDialog.show(); 
            }
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) { // Skipped
            if(isCancelled()){
                this.taskDialog.show();
            } else {
                setupInvoiceAdapter();
                showProgress(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are the important code parts:

```
public class Tb3_Abonnement extends Fragment {

private FetchAbbo task;
...
@Override // If Fragment is visible to user, start asynctask
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

        if (isVisibleToUser) {
                // execute AsyncTask
                task = new FetchAbbo();
                task.execute();
        }

public class FetchAbbo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (Helper.minutes <= 0) {
                task.cancel(true); // Cancel AsyncTask
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()) // Create new AlertDialog
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setTitle("Mededeling:")
                        .setMessage("Uw sessie is verlopen! U dient zich weer opnieuw in te loggen. ")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // Start LoginActivity
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                        .show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... result) {
                if (!this.isCancelled()) { // Executed 
                    Log.e("FetchAbbo: ", "Cancelled!"); // Printed
                    util.disconnect();
                    return null;
                }
                try {
                    Log.e("FetchAbbo: ", "still running!"); 
                    // Do the heavy stuff
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            Log.e("CANCELLED", "TAB3"); // Not printed, onCancelled() not called?
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setupTxtViews();
            mScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Set ScrollView visible

        }
    }
```

Comment: on which version you are testing it.?

Comment: @sourabh bans, Api 23 (marshmellow) if you mean that.

Comment: Is it your device version.

Comment: Yes, it is. I`m testing on a Nexus 9 tablet running latest marshmellow.

Comment: Ok.. see this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16303136/3790052

Comment: @sourabh bans, ok thx for the hint. I will give that a shot and report back.

Comment: Can you add logs at the start of each  method : onPreExecute, doInBackground, onCancelled, onPostExecute, as well as a log just before and after you cancel the task in onPreExecute and see what all logs get printed?

Comment: @Anudeep Bulla, already did and I can tell you onCancelled is not being called, onPostExecute is executed but the AsyncTask received the cancel request. I give your code a try, my main problem is the not showing of the Dialog.

Comment: The dialog is still not showing ? check the value of isCancelled in the onPostExec function.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I applied your code.

Comment: Now it does! I changed your code a little bit. It should be if(!this.isCancelled()) instead of if(this.isCancelled()) in the onPostExecute method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I don't seem to understand the logic of showing the dialog in onPreExecute everytime. Why not try this ?

```
public class FetchAbbo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    AlertDialog taskDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()) // Create new AlertDialog
                                            .setCancelable(false)
                                            .setTitle("Mededeling:")
                                            .setMessage("Uw sessie is verlopen! U dient zich weer opnieuw in te loggen. ")
                                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                       // Start LoginActivity
                                                  }
                                            })
                                           .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                                           .create();
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (Helper.minutes <= 0) {
            task.cancel(true); // Cancel AsyncTask

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... result) {
            if (!this.isCancelled()) { // Executed 
                Log.e("FetchAbbo: ", "Cancelled!"); // Printed
                util.disconnect();
                return null;
            }
            try {
                Log.e("FetchAbbo: ", "still running!"); 
                // Do the heavy stuff
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Log.e("CANCELLED", "TAB3"); // Not printed, onCancelled() not called?
        if(this.isCancelled()){
            this.taskDialog.show();
        }
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(this.isCancelled()){
            this.taskDialog.show();
        } else {
            setupTxtViews();
            mScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Set ScrollView visible
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for showing the right way. As mentioned changing if(this.isCancelled()) to if(!this.isCancelled()) in onPostExecute. finished the job.

Comment: umm, didn't you want the dialog to be shown only if your task was cancelled?

Comment: It should show if the internet session has been expired and then automatically cancel the AsyncTask.

Comment: then it ought to be `this.isCancelled` itself. Maybe the cancelling isnt working . Can you try with `task.isCancelled` instead of `this.isCancelled` ?

Comment: Hmmm yes, something is not working right, suddenly it cancels the AsyncTask immediately, it seems it doesn`t check the (Helper.minutes <= 0) condition anymore.

Comment: I yelled to quick. if (!this.isCancelled()) is not being called anymore, so indeed you`re right, there is something wrong. Any suggestions pls? Maybe that is part of a Fragment is playing a role?

Comment: how dynamic is the change to Helper.minutes ? if it is more or less static, maybe you can quash the entire process. Just check for it even before invoking task.execute, and only invoke task.execute if necessary. If the check fails, you could show the dialog.

Comment: Helper.minutes is a static integer which provides the countdown value, as soon as 0 is reached dialog should be triggered and asynctask stopped. But the weird thing is if I use !this.isCancelled it cancels the asynctask immediately, no matter what value Helper.minutes has. If I use only this.isCancelled without exclamation mark cancel is never been called.

Comment: Got it solved Anudeep Bulla, thx for the pointing out, see my edit2.